# When I click on next song my seekbar sometimes gets updated and sometimes not. I am not getting what's the error in my code probably with the seekbar

Tags: java, android

```
  **Main Activity.java**
```

### This is main activity where I instantiate all methods/objects. Here I use Dexter library to grab files from user's external storage, then I made one method called find songs which helps in finding the path of files and list them accordingly. Then I made another method called display songs which will help in getting the whole size of songs and then display the whole list with their names accordingly. Then with the help of custom adapter I passed my list of songs which is in array named item.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ListView listView;
   String [] items;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listViewSong);
    runtimePermission();

   }
  public void runtimePermission(){
    Dexter.withContext(this)
            





   .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest
   .permissi 
    on.RECORD_AUDIO)
            .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
                @Override
                public void 
    onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport 
       multiplePermissionsReport) 
   {
                    displaySongs();
                }

                @Override
                public void 
   onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> list, 
   PermissionToken permissionToken) {
                    permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
   }
    public ArrayList<File> findSong(File file){
    ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
    Log.d(TAG, "findSong:"+ file.getPath());

    File [] files = file.listFiles();

    if (files!=null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "findSong:"+ files.length);
        for (File singleFile : files) {
            if (singleFile.isDirectory() && !singleFile.isHidden()) {
                arrayList.addAll(findSong(singleFile));
            } else {
                if (singleFile.getName().endsWith(".mp3") &&
                        !singleFile.getName().startsWith(".")) {
                    arrayList.add(singleFile);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return arrayList;
  }


     public void displaySongs(){
     ArrayList<File> mySongs = 
    findSong(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    String [] items = new String [mySongs.size()];
     if(mySongs == null)return; // this is very important function 
    otherwise app will crash

    for (int i=0; i<mySongs.size(); i++){
        items[i] = mySongs.get(i).getName().replace(".mp3",
                "");
      }
      Log.d(TAG, "displaySongs:"+ items.length);
 
    (this, 
   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items);

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, 
   Arrays.asList(items));
    Log.d(TAG, "displaySongs:"+ customAdapter.getCount());
    listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new 
   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int 
   position, long id) {
              String currentSong = (String) 
   listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
   PlayerActivity.class)
                     .putExtra("currentSong", currentSong)
                    .putExtra("position",position)
                    .putExtra("songs",mySongs));


        }
    });
   }
   class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    public android.util.Log Log;
    List<String> names;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context,  List<String> names) {
        super(context,R.layout.list_item ,names);
        this.names=names;
        this.context=context;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup 
    parent) {


        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext()); //inflater is 
    responsible for taking your xml files that defines your layout
       // and converting them into view objects.
        View 
   customview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
        String data=names.get(position);
        //String data1=names.get(position+1);
        TextView tv= 
    (TextView)customview.findViewById(R.id.textsongname);
        tv.setText(data);
        tv.setSelected(true);
        //TextView tv1=(TextView)customview.findViewById(R.id.TeamB);
        //tv1.setText(data1);
        return customview;
    }




    }

  }

  **PlayerActivity.java**
```

### I tried to make a Thread named update seek bar which will update my seek bar to current position after that I applied set on click bar change listener so that whenever user update position of sidebar it should get updated. But error here is that when I run my app using this code on emulator its working completely fine but when installed in my phone 2 errors are coming. One after completion of song its not jumping automatically to the next song and second when user update sidebar and press next, sidebar is not coming to position 0, and this whole error is showing on my phone not in emulator.

```
    public class PlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button play,next,fastforward, previous, fastrewind;
    TextView txtsn, txtsstart, txtsstop;
    SeekBar seekBar;
    BarVisualizer visualizer;
    Thread updateSeekBar;
    String sName;
    public static final String EXTRA_NAME = "song_name";
      static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    int position;
    ArrayList mySongs;
    ImageView imageView;

        @Override
         public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
             if (item.getItemId()== android.R.id.home){
           onBackPressed();
             }
              return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

       }

   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
       if (visualizer != null){
           visualizer.release();
       }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Now Playing");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
       getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

       play = findViewById(R.id.play);
       next = findViewById(R.id.next);
       previous = findViewById(R.id.previous);
       fastforward = findViewById(R.id.fastforward);
       fastrewind = findViewById(R.id.fastrewind);
        txtsn = findViewById(R.id.txtsn);
       txtsstart = findViewById(R.id.txtsstart);
       txtsstop = findViewById(R.id.txtsstop);
       seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
       visualizer = findViewById(R.id.blast);
       imageView = findViewById(R.id.iamgeView);
       if (mediaPlayer != null){
           mediaPlayer.stop();
           mediaPlayer.release();
         }
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        mySongs = (ArrayList) bundle.getParcelableArrayList("songs");
       sName = intent.getStringExtra("currentSong");
       position = bundle.getInt("position",0);
       txtsn.setText(sName);
       txtsn.setSelected(true);
       Uri uri = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());  // uri is 
       usually use tell a content provider what we want to access by 
        reference
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,uri);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

             updateSeekBar = new Thread(){
                  @Override
                   public void run() {
                        int currentPosition = 0;
                 while (currentPosition<mediaPlayer.getDuration()){
                try {
                    currentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                    seekBar.setProgress(currentPosition);
                    sleep(500);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                                   }
                             }
                      }
                 };
             updateSeekBar.start();

 
               seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new 
              SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, 
          boolean fromUser) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                     }

                   @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
               mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
                    }
               });

                String endTime = createTime(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
           txtsstop.setText(endTime);
           final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final int delay = 1000;
           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String currentTime = 
            createTime(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            txtsstart.setText(currentTime);
            handler.postDelayed(this,delay);
        }
               },delay);

               play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                 play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                mediaPlayer.pause();
            }
            else {
                play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                         }
                      }
               });

            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            if(position!=mySongs.size()-1){
                position = position + 1;
            }
            else{
                position = 0;
            }

            Uri uri = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), 
            uri);
            sName = mySongs.get(position).toString();
            txtsn.setText(sName);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            startAnimation(imageView);
            int audiosessionId = mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
            if(audiosessionId!= -1){
                          visualizer.setAudioSessionId(audiosessionId);
                          }

                   }
              });
 

                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new 
                MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                      @Override
                     public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                     next.performClick();
                         }
                       });

               int audiosessionId = mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
              if(audiosessionId!= -1){
                visualizer.setAudioSessionId(audiosessionId);
                }


               previous.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                  mediaPlayer.release();
                   if(position!=0){
                     position = position - 1;
                       }
            else{
                position = mySongs.size() - 1;
            }
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(mySongs.get(position).toString());
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), 
            uri);
            sName = mySongs.get(position).toString();
            txtsn.setText(sName);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            play.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            startAnimation(imageView);

                int audiosessionId = mediaPlayer.getAudioSessionId();
                if(audiosessionId!= -1){
                      visualizer.setAudioSessionId(audiosessionId);
                        }
                     }
              });

              fastforward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
              @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                
          mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()+1000);
                     }
                  }
              });
           fastrewind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                
           mediaPlayer.seekTo(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()-1000);
            }
               }
                   });

          }

                 private boolean isPermissionGranted(){
                  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
                  return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
               }
               else {
               int readExternalStoragePermission = 
              ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
               Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                return readExternalStoragePermission == 
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
                    }
                     }



         public void startAnimation(View view){
              ObjectAnimator animator = 
       ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView,"rotation",0f,360f);
            animator.setDuration(1000);
             AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
             animatorSet.playTogether(animator);
           animatorSet.start();
             }

            public String createTime(int duration) {
             String time = "";
                int min = duration/1000/60;
               int sec = duration/1000%60;
                 time+=min+":";

           if (sec<10) {
             time+="0";
         }
       time+=sec;
       return time;


       }


  }
```

Comment: Please add logcat as well

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.